# Report Folder visible to all users even when not shared

Tags: reporting, reports-folder

I have created one testing report folder and have not shared it no role or user. But users are still able to see that folder and reports inside it. We have enabled analytics folder sharing in ORG. Below screenshot shows the users with folder is shared. I have shared it with myself as manager.

[image]

Users who are able to see this folder have following permissions enabled on their profile.

1. Create and Customize Reports **Checked**
2. Manage Reports in Public Folders **Not Checked**
3. Edit My Reports  **Not Checked**
4. Schedule Reports **Checked**
5. Manage All Private Reports and Dashboards    **Not Checked**
6. Subscribe to Reports **Checked**
7. View Reports in Public Folders   **Checked**

Any thoughts on this. I am not sure if above given permissions are playing any role. Reporting always confuses me in Salesforce :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for profile level permission for that user:
1. View Reports in Public Folders
2. Manage Reports in Public Folders

Should be disabled!